# hermitian matrix, diagonal matrix, definition - considerations

Tags: linear-algebra

$A\in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ is hermitian. Then:
a. $A$ is congruent to some diagonal matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$.
b. if matrix $A$ is positively defined then all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to $1$.
c. if matrix $A$ is positively defined then $A$ is congruent to matrix $I_n$.

b. not true, counterexample:
$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 3 
 \end{array} \right]$.  Of course this matrix is positively defined. Is also hermitian. However, eigenvalues are $5$ and $3$.

c.  Yes, hermitian positively defined matrix $A$ has unique Cholesky decomposition: $A=LL^H$ where $L$ is lower triangular matrix with real positive (strictly) numbers on diagonal. Then $A=LI_nL^H$ and $L$ is nonsingular. Hence, c. is true.

What about b, c?   Could you help me with a. ?

Comment: For (a), recall that any normal matrix (and hence any Hermitian matrix) is unitarily diagonalizable, and the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix are real.

Comment: Could you explain more details ?

Comment: A matrix $A$ is normal if $AA^*=A^*A$ and hence any hermitian matrix is normal. The spectral theorem for normal matrices states that every normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable (i.e, there exists a matrix $U$ such that $U^*=U^{-1}$ and $UAU^*$ is diagonal.) This diagonal matrix must have real entries, as its non-zero entries are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: So all answers should be true, yeah ?